# Installing virtual Machine with virt-install

Tags: go, virtual-machine

```
virt-install \
  -n "NAME" \
  -r 1024 \
  --import \
  --disk path="1703_Disk.img" \
  --accelerate \
  --network network=default \
  --connect=qemu:///system \
  --vnc \
  -v
```

Can someone explain me how to execute this in Go.

Comment: You mean using http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/? What have your tried?

Comment: yes using os/exec in golang

Comment: What problem are you having? What are the [examples](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#pkg-examples) in the documentation missing?

Comment: For future reference: when you have a StackOverflow question closed, instead of re-asking it slightly differently, you should instead just edit [your existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250001/golang-shows-panic-when-executing-a-command). If your edit fixed the question, it would be re-opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`os/exec`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) package is what you're looking for:

```
cmdName := "virt-install"
args := []string{
    "-n", "NAME",
    "-r", "1024",
    "--import",
    "--disk", "path=1703_Disk.img"
    "--accelerate",
    "--network", "network=default",
    "--connect=qemu:///system",
    "-vnc",
    "-v",
}
cmd := exec.Command(cmdName, args...)
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Go API for libvirt, either the one at https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt-go-module or the https://github.com/digitalocean/go-libvirt one. For some tasks, it makes more sense to use that, instead of running libvirt commands as a subprocess.

The `virt-install` case probably makes most sense as a subprocess, however.